# Get value from array of array using map javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I get a value from an array of array using map javascript function.

My response from a query :

```
[ 
    { 
        customer_id: '5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2',
        cars: [ 
            {
                type: 'break', // unique
                serial_number: '0000X523654FE'
                // ... other data, not useful here
            },
            {
                type: 'sport',
                serial_number: '485605FEL45E'
                // ...
            }   
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get `serial_number` string, so here what I did with map javascript function :

```
const serialNumber = response.items.map(element => {

                    return element.cars.map(car => {
                        if (car.type == "sport") {
                            return car.serial_number;
                        }
                    });
                });
```

And I get :

> [ [ '485605FEL45E' ] ]

I would like to get : `'485605FEL45E'`

How can remove the double array ?  I just want the value.

Thank you very much !

EDIT : I didn't specify something important, type is unique, I can't get two sport cars for the same customer.

Comment: `serialNumber[0][0]`????

Comment: you might be after `.flat()` or `.flatMap()` if you want to remove the inner array?

Comment: If you're removing items from the array, you're going to want to use filter too.

Comment: you should be using `.find` on `cars` array not `map`.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I don't want to use this syntax, I want to use directly the value (serialNumber)

Comment: @JoeAllen remember that a map returns you an array!!!

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt yes that's why I think I not using map as I should do

Comment: Looking at your want -. `'485605FEL45E'`, this implies your only want 1 single results..  Is this correct, and if so is it just the first it finds.?   Multiple results would look like -> `['abc', '123']`,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Array.join("").

```js
let items = [{
  customer_id: '5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2',
  cars: [{
      type: 'break',
      serial_number: '0000X523654FE'
    },
    {
      type: 'sport',
      serial_number: '485605FEL45E'
    }
  ]
}]

const serialNumber = items.map(element => {

                return element.cars.map(car => {
                    if (car.type == "sport") {
                        return car.serial_number;
                    }
                });
            });

console.log(serialNumber.join(""));
```

Comment: I accept this answer because with the join function I get exactly what I want : 'value'. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` instead

```js
let data = [{
  customer_id: '5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2',
  cars: [{
      type: 'break',
      serial_number: '0000X523654FE'
    },
    {
      type: 'sport',
      serial_number: '485605FEL45E'
    }
  ]
}]

const serialNumber = data.map(element => {
  let found = element.cars.find(car => {
    if (car.type == "sport") {
      return car.serial_number;
    }
  });
  return (found || {}).serial_number
});

console.log(serialNumber)
```

If there are multiple entries with 'sport' you can use `filter` instead of `find`

```js
let data = [{
  customer_id: '5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2',
  cars: [{
      type: 'break',
      serial_number: '0000X523654FE'
    },
    {
      type: 'sport',
      serial_number: '485605FEL45E'
    },
    {
      type: 'sport',
      serial_number: '657445FEL45E'
    }
  ]
}]

const serialNumber = data.map(element => {
  let found = element.cars.reduce((op, car) => {
    if (car.type == "sport") {
      op.push(car.serial_number)
    }
    return op
  }, []);
  return found.length && found
});

console.log(serialNumber.flat())
```

Comment: Maybe because OP asked for using map function.

Comment: Not me, but what I would say is that remember find will only return 1 item.   What if there are multiple cars that are of type sport.

Comment: not instead, but should be using `find` don't understand a downvote.

Comment: @Keith OP wants to flatten the array so surely there's only one element.

Comment: @AZ_  Not sure why flattening the array should stop the result having multiple serial numbers for multiple sports cars.  IOW: If the user is after all sport cars serial number, find will not work.  Or do you mean because the OP has put wants -> `'485605FEL45E'`  might need to clarify with OP if he really only wants a single result.

Comment: with your solution, I've got this result : ['value'] and no 'value'. It's close to what I want. btw, I've got only ONE type of car in my array, I can't get have two sport car for the same customer_id

Comment: @JoeAllen you can access the index to get desired value, i.e `serialNumber[0]`

Comment: @JoeAllen as keith has a good question what should be the result in case of multiple values, output should still be a string or array ?

Comment: @CodeManiac actually, the array can't contain multiple values for the same type, it's unique and my bad about that, I didn't specify that in my question. Your answer is good if in case of multiple values because I need an array as result. I edited my question. Thank  you for your help !

Comment: @JoeAllen okay always happy to help :), one suggestion is always use a consistent type for output, that will make code easy and also avoid unnecessary check conditions, because if you use two type of output you need to handle cases when there's only one  and when there's more than one element in output

Answer (score 0):

Try using `find()`

```js
let no;
[
    {
        customer_id: '5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2',
        cars: [
            {
                type: 'break',
                serial_number: '0000X523654FE'
            },
            {
                type: 'sport',
                serial_number: '485605FEL45E'
            }
        ]
    }
]
.find(element => { return element.cars.find(i => !!(i.type === 'sport' && (no = i.serial_number))) })

console.log(no)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.find()` like this:

```js
const response = [{
  customer_id: '5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2',
  cars: [{
      type: 'break',
      serial_number: '0000X523654FE'
      // ... other data, not useful here
    },
    {
      type: 'sport',
      serial_number: '485605FEL45E'
      // ...
    }
  ]
}]

let serialNumber = null;

response.find(element => {
  return element.cars.find(car => {
    if (car.type == "sport") {
      serialNumber = car.serial_number;
      return true;
    }
  });
});

console.log(serialNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.find` on `cars` array as following and return the serialNumber to outer `map`

```js
let data = [{
 customer_id: '5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2',
 cars: [{
  type: 'break',
  serial_number: '0000X523654FE'
 },
 {
  type: 'sport',
  serial_number: '485605FEL45E'
 }
 ]
},
{
 customer_id: '5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2',
 cars: [{
  type: 'break',
  serial_number: '0000X523654FE'
 },
 {
  type: 'sport',
  serial_number: '485605FEL45E'
 }
 ]
}]


let out = data.map(({cars}) => cars.find(e => e.type === 'sport').serial_number);
console.log(out)
```